# darken a jumbotron background image on hover using bootstrap 3.0

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a jumbotron containing a background image, and I would like the image to slowly darken when the user scrolls over it.

Here is my html

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1> Insert Welcome Text Here </h1>
            <p> Insert description text here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.jumbotron
{
    height: 800px;
    background-image: url("assets/goodes.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron .container
{
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

.jumbotron h1
{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
}

.jumbotron p
{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Bonus points if you can tell me how to get my image to resize with the window.

Comment: "*Bonus points if you can tell me how to get my image to resize with the window.*" - that would seem to be a different question entirely, but 'resize with the window' *how*? When? When the user hovers the `<img>`? Or when the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Included a transition for animation ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jcxxp2b2/4/))

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="bg-overlay animated">
     <div class="container">
        <h1> Insert Welcome Text Here </h1>
        <p>Insert description text here.</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.animated {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.jumbotron .bg-overlay {
    height: 800px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.jumbotron:hover .bg-overlay {
    height: 800px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a background overlay div after the jumbotron and before the content. On hover of the jumbotron, set the background of the overlay with rgba(0,0,0,0.5) where 0.5 would be 50% alpha

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="bg-overlay">
        <div class="container">
            <h1> Insert Welcome Text Here </h1>
            <p>Insert description text here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then add a css rule

```
.jumbotron:hover .bg-overlay {
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/jcxxp2b2/1/))